# Rails 3 : Matrix Grid View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to display multidimensional array data in a table, like so:

for an sla.expected_billing, there is a grid with 12 periods down the left side (rows)

7 ledger numbers across the top (columns)

amounts in applicable fields, but there may be null values

For instance,

Period 1: Ledger 1 = 400.00, Ledger 2 = null, Ledger 3 = 250.55, Ledger 4 = 500, etc..

Period 2: Ledger 1 = null, Ledger 2 = null, etc...

```
 class ExpectedBilling < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :sla
   belongs_to :period
   belongs_to :ledger  
 end

 class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :expected_billings  
 end

 class Ledger < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :expected_billings  
 end

 class Sla < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :expected_billings  
 end
```

I was thinking the Matrix library and/or Class.transpose might be what I need, but I'm not sure.  When there may be null values in any given array, I'm afraid it won't populate the grid correctly, either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem.  Did you ever figure out an approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would model it slightly differently:

```
 class Sla < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :expected_billing
 end

 class ExpectedBilling < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :periods
   belongs_to :sla
 end

 class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :ledgers
   belongs_to :expected_billing
 end

 class Ledger < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :period
 end
```

To print your table in a view:

```
 <table>
   <!-- insert header row here -->
   <% sla.expected_billing.periods.each do |period| %>
     <tr>
       <!-- insert header column here -->
       <% period.ledgers.each do |ledger| %>
         <td><%= ledger.value %></td>
       <% end %>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
 </table>
```